# Magento2 update layout

Tags: magento2, layout-update

I'm trying to apply any layout changes.

I have:

```
.../view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
```

with code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <remove name="footer" />
    </body>
</page>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Why my footer do not disappear?

When I add same code to any existing core layout - it removes footer properly.

Do I need to add any configuration somewhere to let my layouts work?

Comment: Most probably I got an issue due different versions of files on ftp and on local hdd. In question above posted workable construction. It should work!

Comment: This XML code works. Try to refresh cache.

Comment: Yes. The problem was in cache or in version of file on ftp

Comment: So should the comment be copied to an answer and accepted so this can be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with cache or with version of file on FTP